# Extract query in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Given this url `/calculatePrice?id[0]=123&qty[0]=2&id[1]=456&qty[1]=3`. I am building this to extract the queries:

```
app.use('/calculatePrice', (req,res) => {
var query = {};
query.id = [];
query.qty = [];
    if(req.query.id[i]) query.id.push(req.query.id[i]);
    if(req.query.qty[i]) query.qty.push(req.query.qty[i]);
console.log(query);
}
```

but it doesn't work. How can I extract these queries right ?

Comment: Well `i` isn't defined anywhere that I can see so that would definitely contribute to the problem.

Comment: I know it but I don't know how to fix it. I have tried to use a for loop and set  i<req.query.id.length but it doesn't work as well

Comment: Try `var length = Object.keys(req.query.id).length`. Then loop.

Comment: 'cannot convert undefined or null to object' . Didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Express.js you can access to query params at `req.query` directly.

```
app.use('/calculatePrice', (req,res) => {
  const params = req.query;
  const id = params.id || [];
  const qty = params.qty || [];

  console.log(id);
  console.log(qty);

  ...
}
```

ES6 way using destructuring:

```
app.use('/calculatePrice', (req,res) => {
  const { id, qty } = req.query;

  console.log(id);
  console.log(qty);

  ...
}
```

*Edit:
I have just checked in Express.js v.4 and for passing array elements it can be done setting the index in the array if you want to set the position in the array of the param:

```
/calculatePrice?id[1]=123&qty[1]=2&id[0]=456&qty[0]=3

req.query = {
  id: [456, 123],
  qty: [3, 1],
}
```

Or if you want to save them in the same order they are sent, like this:

```
/calculatePrice?id[]=123&qty[]=2&id[]=456&qty[]=3

req.query = {
  id: [123, 456],
  qty: [1, 3],
}
```

or

```
/calculatePrice?id=123&qty=2&id=456&qty=3

req.query = {
  id: [123, 456],
  qty: [1, 3],
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured this out myself. I can actually use this:

```
app.use('/calculatePrice', (req,res) => {
var query = {};
    if(req.query.id) query.id = req.query.id;
    if(req.query.qty) query.qty = req.query.qty;
console.log(query);
});
```

This will return `{ id: [123,456] , qty: [2,1] }`